# When flow collect stop itself?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-dialogfragment, kotlin-flow

There is `ParentFragment` that shows `DialogFragment`. I `collect` a dialog result through `SharedFlow`. When result received, dialog dismissed. Should I stop `collect` by additional code? What happens when dialog closed, but fragment still resumed?

```
// ParentFragment
private fun save() {
    val dialog = ContinueDialogFragment(R.string.dialog_is_save_task)
    dialog.show(parentFragmentManager, "is_save_dialog")

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        dialog.resultSharedFlow.collect {
            when (it) {
                ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_YES -> {
                    viewModel.saveTask()
                    closeFragment()
                }
                ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_NO -> {
                    closeFragment()
                }
                ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_CONTINUE -> {
                    // dont close fragment
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContinueDialogFragment(
    @StringRes private val titleStringId: Int,
    @StringRes private val messageStringId: Int? = null
) : DialogFragment() {

    private val _resultSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(1)
    val resultSharedFlow = _resultSharedFlow.asSharedFlow()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let { context ->
            AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(getString(titleStringId))
                .setMessage(messageStringId?.let { getString(it) })
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_yes)) { _, _ ->
                    _resultSharedFlow.tryEmit(RESULT_YES)
                }
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_no)) { _, _ ->
                    _resultSharedFlow.tryEmit(RESULT_NO)
                }
                .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.dialog_continue)) { _, _ ->
                    _resultSharedFlow.tryEmit(RESULT_CONTINUE)
                }
                .create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    companion object {
        const val RESULT_YES = 1
        const val RESULT_NO = 0
        const val RESULT_CONTINUE = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Flow completes depends on its original source. A Flow built with `flowOf` or `asFlow()` ends once it reaches the last item in its list. A Flow built with the `flow` builder could be finite or infinite, depending on whether it has an infinite loop in it.

A flow created with MutableSharedFlow is always infinite. It stays open until the coroutine collecting it is cancelled. Therefore, you are leaking the dialog fragment with your current code because you are hanging onto its MutableSharedFlow reference, which is capturing the dialog fragment reference. You need to manually cancel your coroutine or collection.

Or more simply, you could use `first()` instead of `collect { }`.

---

Side note, this is a highly unusual uses of a Flow, which is why you're running into this fragile condition in the first place. A Flow is for a series of emitted objects, not for a single object.

It is also very fragile that you're collecting this flow is a function called `save()`, but you don't appear to be doing anything in `save()` to store the instance state such that if the activity/fragment is recreated you'll start collecting from the flow again. So, if the screen rotates, the dialog will reappear, the user could click the positive button, and nothing will be saved. It will silently fail.

DialogFragments are pretty clumsy to work with in my opinion. Anyway, I would take the easiest route and directly put your behaviors in the DialogFragment code instead of trying to react to the result back in your parent fragment. But if you don't want to do that, you need to [go through the pain of calling back through to the parent fragment](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#PassingEvents). Alternatively, you could use a shared ViewModel between these two fragments that will handle the dialog results.

Comment: `first()` on `SharedFlow` would be works correctly in relation on memory leak bug? Or need to change to just `Flow`. 
Function `save` bad name, rather `onSave` - click handle. Data stores in repository and dont lost.

Comment: `first()` will drop the reference right away, so that should resolve it. I don't see a way to even do this without a SharedFlow or a Channel, both of which have the leak risk. I wasn't commenting on the name of the function. I'm saying you are only saving inside the parent fragment coroutine. If you don't restore the coroutine to be collecting from the possibly new instance of dialog fragment when the parent fragment is recreated, then you will not be saving anything when the user clicks the button.

Comment: But `save()` inside fragment and called immediately after user click. Why fragment can be recreated with the shortest time? I mean "parent" in relation to `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have a memory leak of `DialogFragment`: `ParentFragment` will be referencing the field `dialog.resultSharedFlow` until the corresponding coroutine finishes execution. The latter may never happen while `ParentFragment` is open because `dialog.resultSharedFlow` is an infinite `Flow`. You can call `cancel()` to finish the coroutine execution and make `dialog` eligible for garbage collection:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    dialog.resultSharedFlow.collect {
        when (it) {
            ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_YES -> {
                viewModel.saveTask()
                closeFragment()
                cancel()
            }
            ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_NO -> {
                closeFragment()
                cancel()
            }
            ContinueDialogFragment.RESULT_CONTINUE -> {
                // dont close fragment
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cancel()` relate to `collect` or `scope`? Too hard documentation...

Comment: It will cancel the scope which is provided for coroutine execution.

Comment: Do you mean `lifecycleScope`?

Comment: I don't believe that it cancels the whole `lifecycleScope`,  but only the scope that was created internally to launch a coroutine.